# Border-top on input element is not "straight"

Tags: html, css, border

I'm applying a CSS border to an input element and then applying a thicker `border-top` styling. Why does this have a strange overlapping effect?

```css
input {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 15px solid #414042
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="NOME" required>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/npq7kq9z/3/)**

Here's a detail of the top-left corner:
[image]

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you give a picture of the output and the expected output (mock it in paint if need be)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using box-shadow with no blur, you do have to add a margin though

```css
input {
    background-position: left 10px top 25px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 10px auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #414042;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 15px;
    text-indent: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px -15px 0px 0px #414042;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="NOME" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `border-style` to `solid` and using `border-width` will fix this.

```css
input {
    background-position: left 10px top 25px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 10px auto;
    color: #414042;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 15px;
    text-indent: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-top:15px solid #414042
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="NOME" required/>
```

Comment: Yep.. I need not to change the outside border color